# Multithreading in Qt - doubts and problems

Tags: qt, qt4

nearly searching for hours I became more confused about the Multithreading concept and I need help understanding and implementing it. After searching I have come to the following implementation

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <mythread1.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
mythread abc; 
abc.start();
abc.wait();
return a.exec();
}
```

In above code `mythread.h` is my header file which I created for multithreading and below is my code of mythread1.h

**mythread1.h**

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD1_H
#define MYTHREAD1_H
#include <QtGui>
#include <windows.h>

class mythread : public QThread
{
public:
    void run();
};

void mythread::run()
{

}



#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

Now my questions are

1. I have defined only one function run() and when the thread is initialized how compiler determines it has to execute run() function and what it does when it has multiple functions, I got this question because in main.cpp I just typed abc.start(); and didn't specify what to execute?
2. Inside mythread1.h and in run function I made a infinite loop using while(0<1) and ran the program and to my surprise I was just presented with white screen with 100% CPU usage(not a surprise), but it should run concurrently without interfering with main thread right? then why this is happening?
3. I then used `QFile::copy("pathtomytargetfile","targetpath");` inside the run function inside in mythread1.cpp but that didn't work :O and it didn't copy that file but when i connected it with Push button in main thread then it got successfully copied, why this happened?
4. Does anyone know a simpler way to implement multithreading?

Thank you

Comment: `abc.wait()` - you're waiting until `abc` is done before continuing. Of course it interferes with the main thread!

Comment: Then how can I make it run concurrently? should I remove that line? then it will run in background without interfering main thread? I have read somewhere that I have to put that line so that thread gets closed before exiting the application? Can you pls clarify, I am new to Qt

Comment: After `a.exec()` returns, you can `abc.quit()` or `abc.exit(0)` - sounds like you really need to start by [reading the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qthread.html)

Comment: Can I get explanation for my remaining questions pls?

Comment: Here's a great set of tutorials to get you started with threading in Qt: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaGqGhRW5Ks
I would go through all of them if you are still learning about the basics of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: run method should be protected!

Secondly, what do you mean by "I have defined only one function run()". You defined method, not function. `abc.start()` means that abc instance of mythread will start and use it's entry point method `void run()`. You can't declare more than one method with same signature. And if you wonder how it calls your `run()` instead of `QThread::run()` then you need to read something about virtual methods in C++

Ad. 3: How can we tell why your file didn't copy? Check what errors QFile provides you. Change your code something like that:

```
QFile f("pathtomytargetfile");
if( ! f.copy("targetpath") )
{
     qDebug() << f.errorString();
}
```

It will provide you some usefull info

Answer (score 1):

My answer might confuse you even more, but the following links are worth reading in my opinion:

1. [This](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) is an article by the engineer who introduced the `QThread` class. He apologizes for suggesting that inheriting from `QThread` is the way to go.
2. [This](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) article shows you, how you should do it (strictly speaking -- inheriting from `QThread` will work as well, it just is not as nice design-wise).
3. [On this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html) you can find an overview of multithreading techniques that Qt offers and some help deciding which one you should use for your specific problem.

HTH